# Color the column of a latex table produced by xtable

Tags: r, sweave

How can I use the R xtable package to produce a table with a colored column? [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7952/how-to-create-coloured-tables-with-sweave-and-xtable) post shows how to color a row, but I can't figure out how to do the same for columns.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\columncolor` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|>{\columncolor{olive!50}}c|c|}    %% Color 4th column
\hline
Username & Sample & Filename & Sequence & Comments \\ \hline
 1& 2& 3& 4& 5\\
 3& 5& 8& 9& 23\\
 1& 2& 3& 4& 5\\
 3& 5& 8& 9& 23\\
 1& 2& 3& 4& 5\\
 3& 5& 8& 9& 23\\
 1& 2& 3& 4& 5\\
 3& 5& 8& 9& 23\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]